# Changing the Linux Hostname with python

Tags: python, linux, random, text-files, hostname

I am trying to change the linux hostname by having a python program randomly select a name from a file then setting that as the host name. The code works only when the random digit value is 1. What am I doing wrong? The code I am using is below.

```
import random
import os
import socket

contents=[]

with open("/root/Desktop/names.txt") as rnd:
    for line in rnd:
        line=line.strip()
        contents.append(line)
name = contents[random.randint(0,len(contents)-1)]
rnd.close()
name = "hostname -b "+name
os.system(name)
hostname = socket.gethostname()
print "Hostname:", hostname
```

Comment: What's in `names.txt`? You could also try `print contents` after reading the file.

Comment: `with open() as rnd: ... rnd.close()` you don't need to close a file resource that has a context manager (aka, `with`).

Comment: I need it to put in the command line, hence the os.system(), the randomly chosen name. name.txt is the text file in which it is randomly choosing the name from.

Comment: Please use random.choice, you current code is bad for pykarma, the name changing part is doable by following this. http://www.howtogeek.com/50631/how-to-change-your-linux-hostname-without-rebooting/

Comment: What makes you think that `os.system('hostname -b foo')` succeeded? You should print the value of name to confirm that the `random` part works. Perhaps you are running this as non-root? (A [similar program](http://ideone.com/qXhgLg) works for me.)

Comment: I am running in root. I know its a bad idea but I'm doing it anyway. Also hostname -b foo would pertinently change the hostname to foo without rebooting. The os.system() command runs the command as if it was in the terminal. Also the random code does work. If I add a print command it prints the right name, but if it is not at the top of the list in the .txt file then the hostname command returns an error.

Comment: Also consider replacing `os.system()` with `subprocess.check_call(['hostname','-b','--',name])` and the loop with `with ... as rnd: contents = list(line.strip() for line in rnd)`. You may also want to strip empty lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `random` module provides a function to select a random element from a sequence:

```
name = random.choice(contents)
```

That does exact what you want, I think. Furthermore, it has the advantage that if `contents` is empty for whatever reason, an exception will be thrown.

---

Update:

In passing, you don't need to call `rnd.close()` since you are using a context manager when you open the file in the first place (`with open(...) as rnd:`) - it will be called automatically when you leave the scope of the `with` clause.

Comment: Sorry I found the solution. I had spaces in my name.txt file. The first name was 'John' and the others were a first name (space) last name. With removing the spaces in the names in the .txt file it solved the problem. Thank you for all your help.